# Can I touch the metal frame or do I need to ground it?

Tags: ground, wiring, light

I live in Eu and I connected the blue - neutral and the brown - hot to the light jack. There is no third ground wire in the cable and i am afraid to touch the black steel frame - is it dangerous, should I ground it or is it not necessary?

Please help

Edit and update:

I added new photos

I connected the blue neutral wire to the T210 and the brown wire to the OE50(or something like that) There is no label except class 1 insulation symbol on the light bulb socket and again class 1 on the electric cable and some others which I don't know what they mean.

No double insulation symbol so I guess I need to ground or buy a cable with ground wiring.

Here are the photos.

[image: picture1]
[image: picture2]
[image: picture3]
[image: picture4]

---

Update 2 and new related question.

I found out some celing lamp was wired as seen in photo. It is same level 1 insulation and the ground is not connected to nothing. Was that done wrong?
Should I turn off electricity at the fuse box as precatution and connect green/yellow - ground wire to that steel bolt, would that ground it?

[image: Picture 1]

Comment: A good clear photo of the approvals label would help... does it have the double insulation symbol?

Comment: Do you have RCDs fitted?

Comment: This is an electricity question (not electronics) and should be in "Home improvement".

Comment: How are you planning to ground it if there is no mains earth in your room? The pipes? In your case neutral is connected to the earth at the utility I suppose.

Comment: Yes you are correct, Actually the radiator pipes are near but it would look ugly. Better to buy appropriate cable with double insulated socket for what I need.

Comment: In your photo the black frame looks floating varnished and painted. And it is very unlikely that the brown hot wire will touch to the frame. And in worst case if there is RCD installed you would still be safe.

Comment: @ty_1917 fact of neutral being connected to safety ground at the utility does not help you *here*.  If anything it creates a false confidence that neutral is non-deadly.  If that were true, they wouldn't put insulation on it :)

Comment: Yes I didnt suggest to connect chassis to the neutral it can still be lethal.

Comment: Ok I won't risk it.

Comment: Looking at the first photo, can anyone see if that screw and washer if for attaching the earth?

Answer (score 2):

It's class 1.

> With Class 1 appliances, the user is protected by a combination of basic insulation and the provision of an earth connection, thus providing two levels of protection. When PAT Testing Class 1 appliances, Earth Continuity and Insulation Resistance tests are carried out.
>   [(source)](https://www.intersafe.co.uk/news/What-does-Class-I-and-Class-II-mean-when-it-comes-to-PAT-Testing/)

It needs a ground connection on the metalwork. There should be a grounding screw there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the lamp holder is isolated from ground. This may be why it did not have a ground. I believe this to be true because the connections go through the ceramic and the screw that holds the assembly is offset. A ground is a good thing if you have it available but if your rules are like ours a lamp holder with non conductive parts is not required to have a ground.